# where to place my script tag before closing of</body> or after it

Tags: javascript, html, performance, dom

As we many of know that we have to include external jsscript file at the end of page.
for performance and usability purpose.

I want to know the correct place where to place it.

means

```
<boby>
<!--html here -- >
<script src= ""> <!--  here ???  -- >
</body>
<script src= ""><!--  here ???  -- >
```

before the closing of script tag or after the closing of script . Is there any avantage of putting inside or outisde of body tag.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What would this have to do with "usability purposes"?

Answer (score 1):

Placing it *after* the body isn't even an option, script tags cannot go there. That would result in an invalid HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you should put this before closing of body tag, but at the end where all other elements end
Like

```
    <body>
    <h1></h1>
    ... 
    .... 
<!-- you shud place here -->
<script>
</script>
   </body>
```

And to your second question, you cannot just put after body tag, except in `<head></head>` section. This is called calling js asynchronusly (in body tag generally in footer section )